# SQL gaps in dates

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to find gaps in the a table based on a state code the tables look like this.

StateTable:

```
StateID (PK) | Code
--------------------
1            | AK
2            | AL
3            | AR
```

StateModel Table:

```
StateModelID | StateID | EfftiveDate            | ExpirationDate
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1            |  1      | 2012-06-28 00:00:00.000| 2012-08-02 23:59:59.000
2            |  1      | 2012-08-03 00:00:00.000| 2050-12-31 23:59:59.000
3            |  1      | 2055-01-01 00:00:00.000| 2075-12-31 23:59:59.000
```

The query I am using is the following:

```
Declare @gapMessage varchar(250)
SET @gapMessage = ''

select
@gapMessage = @gapMessage + 
  (Select StateTable.Code FROM StateTable where t1.StateID = StateTable.StateID) 
  + ' Row ' +CAST(t1.StateModelID as varchar(6))+' has a gap with '+
  CAST(t2.StateModelID as varchar(6))+ CHAR(10)
   from StateModel t1
   inner join StateModel t2
    on
       t1.StateID = t2.StateID
       and DATEADD(ss, 1,t1.ExpirationDate) < t2.EffectiveDate
       and t1.EffectiveDate < t2.EffectiveDate

 if(@gapMessage != '')
 begin         
Print 'States with a gap problem'
PRINT @gapMessage
 end
 else
 begin
PRINT 'No States with a gap problem'
 end
```

But with the above table example I get the following output:

```
States with a gap problem
AK Row 1 has a gap with 3
AK Row 2 has a gap with 3
```

Is there anyway to restructure my query so that the gap between 1 and 3 does not display because there is not a gap between 1 and 2?
I am using MS sql server 2008
Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by not a gap between 1 and 2?  Also there is not enough database information to provide an answer.

Comment: Since my definition of a gap is greater than 1 second from ExpirationDate and EffectiveDate So the EffectiveDate of StateModelID 2 is 1 second ahead of the ExpirationDate of StateModelID 1 so for StateID 1 has one active record from  2012-06-28 to 2050-12-31 23:59:59.000.

Comment: TSQL cover SyBase, SQL Server 2000, SQL Server 2008, etc - Which RDBMS are you using?  Also, will these records always have consecutive IDs, or could they be `1, 5, 12`?  And what indexes do you have on the tables?

Comment: Using SQL Server 2008 The StateModelID is an Auto Increment so they could be seperated like 1, 5, 12, 72 and there are no indexes on the tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH
  sequenced AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StateID ORDER BY EfftiveDate) AS SequenceID,
    *
  FROM
    StateModel
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sequenced    AS a
INNER JOIN
  sequenced    AS b
    ON  a.StateID    = b.StateID
    AND a.SequenceID = b.SequenceID - 1
WHERE
  a.ExpirationDate < DATEADD(second, -1, b.EfftiveDate)
```

To make this as effective as possible, also add an index on `(StateID, EfftiveDate)`

Comment: I like how we did the same thing, yet different in almost every way.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to just give credit to MatBailie, but don't have the points to do it yet, so I thought I would help out anyone else looking for a similar solution that may want to take it a step further like I needed to.  I have changed my application of his code (which involves member enrollment) to the same language as the example here.

In my case, I needed these things:

1. I have two similar tables that I need to develop into one total table.  In this example, let's make the tables like this:  SomeStates + OtherStates = UpdatedTable.  These are UNIONED in the AS clause.
2. I didn't want to remove any rows due to gaps, but I wanted to flag them on the StateID level.  This is added as an additional column 'StateID_GapFlag'.
3. I also wanted to add a column to hold the oldest or MIN(EffectiveDate).  This would be used in later calculations of SUM(period) to get a total duration, excluding gaps.  This is the column 'MIN_EffectiveDate'.

   ```
   ;WITH sequenced     
   ( SequenceID
   ,EffectiveDate
   ,ExpirationDate)
   AS
       (select 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StateID ORDER by EffectiveDate) as SequenceID,
       * from  (select EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate from SomeStates
                   UNION ALL
               (select EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate from OtherStates)
               ) StateModel
       where 
           EffectiveDate > 'filter'
       )
   Select DISTINCT 
           IJ1.[MIN_EffectiveDate]
           ,coalesce(IJ2.GapFlag,'') as [MemberEnrollmentGapFlag]
           ,EffectiveDate
           ,ExpirationDate
   into UpdatedTable 
   from sequenced seq
           inner join 
               (select StateID, min(EffectiveDate) as 'MIN_EffectiveDate'
                   from sequenced 
                   group by StateID
               ) IJ1
           on seq.member# = IJ1.member
           left join
               (select a.member#, 'GAP' as 'StateID_GapFlag'
                   from sequenced a
                   inner join 
                       sequenced b
                           on a.StateID = b.StateID
                           and a.SequenceID = (b.sequenceID - 1)
                       where a.ExpirationDate < DATEADD(day, -1, b.EffectiveDate)
               ) LJ2
           on seq.StateID = LJ2.StateID
   ```

Comment: I added "<pre><code>SQL code </code></pre>" before and after your code and it get formatted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER` to provide an ordering of stateModel's for each state, then check that the second difference for consecutive rows doesn't exceed 1.  Something like:

```
;WITH Models (StateModelID, StateID, Effective, Expiration, RowOrder) AS (
    SELECT StateModelID, StateID, EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StateID, ORDER BY EffectiveDate)
    FROM StateModel
)
SELECT F.StateModelId, S.StateModelId
FROM Models F
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT M.StateModelId
    FROM Models M
    WHERE M.RowOrder = F.RowOrder + 1
      AND M.StateId = F.StateId
      AND DATEDIFF(SECOND, F.Expiration, M.Effective) > 1
) S
```

This will get you the state model IDs of the rows with gaps, which you can format how you wish.